# Why does the jenkinsfile use a closure in this way?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

It's a common pattern to write Jenkins pipeline code like this:

```
def call(body) {    
    def config = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = config
    body()
}
```

I'm not sure how to word this simply, but this closure get implicitly imported and can be called by the file name of the `.groovy` file it lives in.

I call it like:

```
MyClosure { myarg = 'sdfsdf' }
```

I not entirely sure what this is doing. It's doing `call(body)` and then assigning `body` as the delegate. so that means the closure I pass it is the delegate, but isn't that just the owner? Wah? me confused.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When this runs, it is creating an empty map (`config`). Then it is telling the closure (`body`) to look at the delegate first to find properties by setting its resolveStrategy to be the constant `Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST`. Then it assigns the `config` map as the delegate for the body object.

Now when you execute the `body()` closure, the variables are scoped to the `config` map, so now `config.myarg = 'sdfsdf'`.

Now later in the code you can have easy access to the map of values in `config`.

`body` is the *owner*, and by default is the *delegate*. But when you switch the *delegate* to be `config`, and tell it to use the delegate first, you get the variables `config`'s scope.

Comment: What if I didn't switch the delegate to config? Body would be the delegate? If that was the case would I have no way of accessing the myarg that gets passed in?

Comment: Right. `body` is a variable that points to an anonymous function. If you didn't change the delegate, then myarg would be set to 'sdfsdf' in the scope of that function and as soon as that function exits, that value is gone. But if you delegate to the map object, it sets the property on the object, which you can now get to.

Comment: Actually body does not point to a function. It's an instance of a closure.

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it. What if `config` is not a map. Say for example it's a function or just a variable like `def config = 123`. What happens in this case if we run the above code?